# Why is this action.type not firing in the Reducer of my React/Redux App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

totally stumped, I have an action which sets a state - isAuthenticated boolean and user object based on whether a user is logged in or not.

The action is definitely firing, the auth reducer is correctly running, but the case isn't being triggered so the state isn't updated:

**Action:**

```
export const SET_CURRENT_USER = 'SET_CURRENT_USER'

export function setCurrentUser (user) {
  console.log(SET_CURRENT_USER)
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    user
  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'
import SET_CURRENT_USER from '../actions/authActions'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {}
}

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

      // console.log('action.type = ', action.type) <<< This is outputting the correct action type: SET_CURRENT_USER
      switch (action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_USER:
          console.log('set cur user reducer') // this is not running
          console.log(!isEmpty(action.user)) // this is not running
          return {
            isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.user),
            user: action.user
          }
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
The action is being called on login, and also in the root index.js file with:

```
store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwt.decode(localStorage.getItem('token'))))
```

**Store setup is as follows:**
Index.js:

```
const store = configureStore()
```

configureStore.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from './reducers/index'

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
  return store
}

export default configureStore
```

Root Reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

import auth from './auth'
import transactions from './transactions'
import expenditure from './expenditure'
import income from './income'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  transactions,
  expenditure,
  income,
  routing: routerReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: can you do a console log for SET_CURRENT_USER also ?

Comment: Hey @ArshabhAgarwal - yes I did that, correctly outputs the action type string.

Comment: How're you setting up the reducer? Do you have the store config code?

Comment: Hey @TomWalters - yep will update post

Comment: BTW, you should return a new copy of the state instead, you might usually want to do return `Object.assign({}, state, { isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.user), ... })`

Comment: Thanks @FacundoLaRocca, have updated. Just need the reducer case to run now >.<

Comment: try this `import * as actions from '../actions/authActions'` and then use it as `actions.SET_CURRENT_USER`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it is not exported as default so should be imported using curly braces

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from '../actions/authActions'
```

Comment: ARGHHHHHH! Haha. I have been staring at this for over an hour. Thank you @duwalanise - star